# How to handle collapsible menus from Bootstrap on React

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have this very small piece of code, in React:

```
<ul className="nav" id="side-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#" aria-expanded="false">
      <span className="nav-label">Account</span><span className="fa arrow">&nbsp;</span>
    </a>
    <ul className="nav nav-second-level collapse" aria-expanded="false">
      <li>
        <a href="/test">Test</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/test">Test</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The collapsible menu does not works. The click does nothing. I'm assuming it is because React does not handle the actual click on the first level nav `<li>`, and thus the second level nav's are not displayed. Is that a safe assumption?

If it is, then how to handle it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap relies on jQuery, so without that it won't work. You could at that, but it's generally considered bad practice to use both jQuery and React.

Another option is rewrite the functionality into your own component. What I'd suggest is actually using a package like [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/).

Comment: I have tested React Bootstrap, was curious how to use that with a template. But I think that I can copy all the CSS to react-bootstrap, and then use it that way. Will test and report my findings.